# How to make Webhook for Slot Filling in Api.ai using backend Node js

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

how to do slot filling in **api.ai** using web-hooks for back-end **Node.js**, could you please any one let us know the process. Here is the sample response I have for creating sample webhook.

```
 return res.json({
                speech: "here is the sample one.",
                displayText: "here is the sample one ",
                data: {...},
                contextOut: [{"name":"weather", "lifespan":2, "parameters":
                             {"city":"Rome"}}],
                source: "from API"
        });
```

Comment: But where are you doing slotfilling? Slotfilling reflects that you are filling parameters with somevalue in your webhook.

Comment: yes I was did one sample use case for hotel room booking when end user asking about the how many rooms do you have still in your hotel then we need to trigger back-end api and need fill the slot, There I am using the slot filling, finally I have completed that peace, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the answer first we need to enable the option called Domains, which is available in fulfillment tab in that we need to change option to **Enable Webhook for all Domains**. Below is the sample response with Node.js API, Using this response I am responding to the api.ai console. If any one having queries please post it @Here, Thank you.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const restService = express();

restService.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

restService.use(bodyParser.json());

restService.post('/echo', function(req, res) {
    var speech = req.body.result && req.body.result.parameters && req.body.result.parameters.response1 ? req.body.result.parameters.response2 : "Seems like some problem."

    return res.json({
        speech: speech,
        displayText: speech,
        source: 'webhook-echo-sample'
    });
});
```

Comment: Any Idea how to do the same in v2 api?

Comment: Yeah, Same thing be like v1 , Just you need to change response format, Which is mentioned in below link please go through that. Thank you.
Link : https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v1-v2-migration-guide-fulfillment